# sort by on elasticsearch not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ES query as something like below:

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"should":[{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"should":[{"match":{"*login*":{"query":"jyo","operator":"and"}}}]}}],"boost":1.34}}]}}]}},"sort":[{"_uid":"desc"}]}
The output is :

{
    "took": 77,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 33,
        "successful": 33,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 4,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "hobbes1.qa_en_19_2",
                "_type": "esuser",
                "_id": "6",
                "_score": null,
                "sort": [
                    "esuser#6"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "hobbes1.qa_en_19_2",
                "_type": "esuser",
                "_id": "5",
                "_score": null,
                "sort": [
                    "esuser#5"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "hobbes1.qa_en_19_2",
                "_type": "esuser",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": null,
                "sort": [
                    "esuser#4"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "hobbes1.qa_en_19_2",
                "_type": "esuser",
                "_id": "10003",
                "_score": null,
                "sort": [
                    "esuser#10003"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If it is sorting by _id, then shouldn't 10003 be at the top? I am using elasticsearch version 1.7. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `_id` is not a `number` but a `string`, "10003" is less than "4", "5" or "6" on string comparation.

Comment: Thanks . What if I want to do integer sorting on uid. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You may duplicate the `_id` field to a filed in the `source`, and manly set the mapping type to `integer` if necessary, then sorting on the new field when querying.

Comment: how to duplicate it?